# Apex inbound email handler is not working when email is sent to Salesforce from Surface device

Tags: apex-email-service

We have a requirement in which if a User sends an email to a particular email address( say Client@Email.com) then new custom object record needs to be created. To implement this, we created an Email Service in Salesforce with say LogicClass(which contains logic to create custom object record) as the Apex handler and created an Email Address(which is generated by Salesforce, say autgen@email.com) under this Service. And we have an Outlook rule created for Client@Email.com in such a way that if Client@Email.com receives any email, it will be forwarded to autgen@email.com which triggers the LogicClass and creates record in Salesforce accordingly.

This functionality is working when an email is sent from outlook web app using Internet Explorer browser from Desktop or Laptop or Mobile device. But when an email is sent from outlook web app using Internet Explorer browser from Surface device, this functionality is not working and even logs are not generated in this case.

(A Case has been raised to Salesforce and awaiting their response.)

Please let us know if there is a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be an Outlook issue unless you have any indication that Salesforce is the source of the problem.

Comment: But it works for other devices such as Desktop, Laptop and Mobile with the same outlook web mail. Only with the Surface device it is not working.